# Cannot resolved method Query in Apollo Graphql in android?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

When I write code like this in my MainActivity class under user-defined method

```
public void getPosts(){
   MyApolloClient.getApolloClient().query();  <-- this query cannot  resolved }
```

Here is my MyApolloclient Class

```
public class MyApolloClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cjc9dyua73w530117pid7omxd";
private static ApolloClient apolloClient;

public static ApolloClient getApolloClient(){

    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build();

    apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
            .serverUrl(BASE_URL)
            .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    return apolloClient;

}
}
```

---

Apollo already generated AllPostQuery Class but it fails to get Query method in my MainActivity class.